# WooCommerce - Can't remove items from cart

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I can't remove any item from a cart clicking on the *red x button*. There's no error and I don't even use any caching plugins. **The only possible solution is to remove the WooCommerce session cookie.** Please, can you help me to solve this problem?

[image]
*Cart*

[image]
*WooCommerce session cookie - **wp_woocommerce_session_{#hash}***

Some specs

- WooCommerce ver. 2.5.5
- Wordpress ver. 2.5.2
- No caching/minify plugins
- **Wordpress theme Optimizer 0.4.1**

WooCommerce plugins used (disabling them didn't help)

- YITH WooCommerce Uploads
- YITH WooCommerce Cart Messages
- WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities
- WooCommerce - All in One SEO Pack
- WC Simple Product Badge

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would advise switching to a default theme to see if it's your theme. If that's the problem you should contact your theme's author.

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks for you answer! switched back to Twenty Fourteen, didn't helped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Didn't set the cart page in WooCommerce settings. **Solved.**

Comment: Could you explain what you changed in settings? I have the same problem and I'm not sure what you mean "set the cart page".

Comment: @Kristis went to the settings and searched for the part where you set the pages. Just a basic assign..